# Fail to align buttons with angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple task which is to have:

- Two buttons to the left of the screen
- And one button to the right of the screen

I looked in the angular material website but still something is not sitting right:

```xml
<div layout="row" layout-align="start none">
    <button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="func()" class="md-primary">
      First
    </button>
    <button md-button (click)="func2()">
      Second
    </button>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="end start">
        <button class="md-button" md-button (click)="func3()">
          Third
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Why you put `<div layout="row" layout-align="end start"> ... </div>` **inside** `<div layout="row" layout-align="start none">` ? 
I think putting `end start` sibling of `start none` resolve your case.

For example:

```xml
<div layout="row" layout-align="start none">

        <button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="someFunc()" class="md-primary">First</button>
        <button md-button (click)="someFunc2()">Second</button>
</div>
<div layout="row" layout-align="end start">
        <button class="md-button" md-button (click)="someFunc3()">Third</button>
</div>
```